# Typescript - force value to be a proprerty of an interface

Tags: typescript, discord.js

I'm trying to create some kind of factory to create class for a type of some events emitted by `discord.js`.

In this example, `ClientEvents` are defined by `discord.js`, `EventInterface` define the format of the object/class used in the factory and `MessageCreateEvent` is a exemple of the implementation.

I want to force the `name` value of the implemented class to be a key of `ClientEvent` (like in the code below but it's not working) and I want to type the args of `execute` to be the associated type of the given key in `ClientEvent`. For example, if the `name` is `messageCreate`, and `DontKnowType` should be a `Message`.

```ts
type Message = unknown;
type DontKnowType = unknown;

interface ClientEvents {
  messageCreate: [message: Message];
}


interface EventInterface<T extends keyof { [x: string]: ClientEvents}> {
    name: T,
    execute: (interactObject: DontKnowType) => Promise<void | undefined>;
}

class MessageCreateEvent implements EventInterface<'messageCreate'> {
    public name = 'messageCreate';

    public async execute(interactObject: DontKnowType): Promise<void | undefined> {
        console.info(`Message from ${interactObject?.user.tag}`);
    }
}
```

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Please provide reproducible example where all types are defined

Comment: `public name: keyof ClientEvents = 'messageCreate'`? Not really clear what you're after here.

Comment: I want a way to force `interactObject` the be the same type of `ClientEvents[this.name]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be match clearer If you provide examples or comments on how your example should work, and how shouldn't.

But I altered your code to make validation of Message**Event classes by `EventInterface` and force name to be part of Message**Event interface.

```
interface EventInterface<T extends keyof ClientEvents> {
  name: T
  execute: (...args: ClientEvents[T]) => Promise<void>;
}
class MessageCreateEvent implements EventInterface<'messageCreate'>{
    public name = 'messageCreate' as const;
    public async execute(message: Message): Promise<void> {
        console.info(`Message from ${message!.user!.tag!}`);
    }
}
```

[full example in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAshDO8CGBzaBeKBvAvgbgChRIoARAewDtgBpS8gdwBVwMoBXSga3ocsIIBLahABOAMyQBjaAGEANoIjUAogDdlweNgJQoAWwTI0s0RCTAIALigBtQ4lTXYRpwF1COAkVZQIADwgpdksAMU4pYEEqAB4mP39LSgATbS4IEHJxKAUlVQ1qeAA+KEwACgA6KqRRFHgbXM11TXhbJjcASlKSgAVRcn1BeAgYtXJBZKKBYUsJaWhm6gBJETmZOISk1Kh0zOzG-JaSrF0oSiRDGyZTgKCQ50rq2vqcxSaCrTbO7qg+gaGRmMJlMCF4CFJ5EhEC5HCYzBYIItgFBBPowPIIIZClAkStZpJ1gByBzGCCmcyWQlFE56PRgdgAI0UUjOFzYxNccIpEEJUChUCkVHgwEItKg9KZghZUJAlBZt2CljKJKcNjgsIgHRsf0Gw1G40mOjFYsFlHg5AxFWE4nIZQABurSVBxP19FAACRYFVoACEFXYw1EfuAqB9ODtHVFtK8YIhUO0jqcKzUSEUySRKLRGKxWhxHzxYgJIw5GvJCKpNNpEuZrMMpSgJdJydTE15-NNwqjdMZNZlcoSdyV3ucibQABoDJyIAAmNVTrW-V0A-XAo3GvQdi0QK2UG320fQF0DD1eqd+gNiYOh8OR056GNAA)

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: This is clearly what I want, thank you ! I could not find it my self because I did not think to add `...` before `args` (this is because `ClientEvents` format look like `messageCreate: [message: Message]` and not `messageCreate: Message` ?

Comment: It depends... `messageCreate: [message: Message]` allows you to describe all function arguments, and with `messageCreate: Message` you can define the type only for one argument: `execute: (arg0: ClientEvents[T], ...args: any[]) => Promise<void>;`